# How to optimize this mysql query with where, order by as well as pagination?

Tags: mysql

The query is as follows:

```
select * from table 
where category in ('A', 'B') 
order by upload_time desc 
limit 60, 20;
```

where `category` is of type `varchar(60)`, and `upload_time` is `datetime`.

Could anyone tell me where to create index is most suitable for this scenario? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out how the query optimizer regards your query by using "`EXPLAIN SELECT ...`", but I'll admit the output can be hard to understand for a beginner.

You can put an index on category because you're using that in a WHERE clause. You can also put an index on upload_time because you are sorting on it.

Finally, you can use something other than "`select *`" because that will bring back all the columns in the table and if you aren't using them all you're doing more I/O than you need.

Comment: Be a little wise though when you create your category index - as it's a relatively long varchar column, you may not want to index the whole thing, only the first `n` characters. Depending on your data, you may find that experimenting with your cardinality values at smaller index lengths yields acceptable results whilst drastically reducing the size of the index.

Comment: Thanks bro! There's something I don't get in your post. What do you mean by `use something other than select *`?

Comment: I mean select just what you want: "select id, name, thing1, thing2 from ...". That way you don't pull out of the table anything you don't really need.